# symbolicatecrash doesn't resolve my app objects

Tags: xcode, symbolicatecrash

I am able to use symbolicatecrash command to symbolicate the crash log and it all works fine except it only resolves system symbols, but all my app's object remain as memory address.. like the following.  It is the same result when I use xcode to import the crash, did I miss something in the app build settings?

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x3436488f __exceptionPreprocess + 163
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x36c65259 objc_exception_throw + 33
2   CoreFoundation                      0x34364789 +[NSException raise:format:] + 1
3   Foundation                          0x34bb63a3 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 91
4   MycoolAp                            0x0018330f 0xbb000 + 819983
5   UIKit                               0x36d5fc8b -[UIViewController view] + 167
6   UIKit                               0x36d6c1e9 -[UIViewController contentScrollView] + 25
7   UIKit                               0x36d6c059 -[UINavigationController _computeAndApplyScrollContentInsetDeltaForViewController:] + 37
8   UIKit                               0x36d6bf3f -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 35
9   UIKit                               0x36d6b7c1 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 501
10  UIKit                               0x36d6b503 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded] + 251
11  UIKit                               0x36d5faff -[UINavigationController pushViewController:transition:forceImmediate:] + 807
12  UIKit                               0x36d5f7d5 -[UINavigationController pushViewController:animated:] + 37
13  Tapsbook                            0x001914f1 0xbb000 + 877809
14  UIKit                               0x36dd893d -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 945
15  UIKit                               0x36e52627 -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 159
16  Foundation                          0x34be8933 __NSFireDelayedPerform + 415
17  CoreFoundation                      0x34338a33 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 15
18  CoreFoundation                      0x34338699 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 365
19  CoreFoundation                      0x3433726f __CFRunLoopRun + 1207
20  CoreFoundation                      0x342ba4a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 301
21  CoreFoundation                      0x342ba36d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
22  GraphicsServices                    0x3829c439 GSEventRunModal + 137
23  UIKit                               0x36d54cd5 UIApplicationMain + 1081
24  MycoolAp                            0x000bff75 0xbb000 + 20341
25  MycoolAp                            0x000bd360 0xbb000 + 9056
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, find out why, it was because my spotlight indexing server was disabled (I don't like it generated huge indexing files and heat up my CPU) so the xcode cannot find the right app dSYM, once I let the spotlight index finish, this problem is then fixed.